# Add a list of key value pairs to existing list when the key is not available

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, json-normalize

I Have a column that contains json string across each row.
I am converting them to a list and using json normalize to extract the information in the form of a data frame.

Consider extras as the column here in the dataframe data and i first use the below query to extract the data in the form of a list

```
extras = extras.extras.apply(json.loads).values.tolist()
```

Now on converting this to a list i extract the information out using the below command

```
extras_df = pd.json_normalize(
extras,
record_path =['inventory_data'], 
meta=['job_id','margin','stock','mrp',discount],
record_prefix = 'product_',
sep="_",
errors='ignore' )
```

I get a key error here because a few lists in the above extras list that i extracted doesnt have the 'inventory_data' in them. I need to be able to add an empty key value pair of size and quantity next to it if the information is not available

Same data below

```
extras = [
  {'job_id': 'b1b4354e-7869-442a-8763-dafbd9f33a5a',
  'stock': '0',
  'mrp': 1899.0,
  'discount': 55.0,
  'inventory_data': [{'size': 'M', 'quantity': '0'},
   {'size': 'L', 'quantity': '0'},
   {'size': 'XL', 'quantity': '0'},
   {'size': 'S', 'quantity': '0'}],
  'margin': 'Low',
},
 {'job_id': 'b1b4354e-7869-442a-8763-dafbd9f33a5a',
  'stock': '0',
  'mrp': 999.0,
  'discount': 50.0,
  'inventory_data': [{'size': 'L', 'quantity': '0'},
   {'size': 'S', 'quantity': '0'},
   {'size': 'M', 'quantity': '0'},
   {'size': 'XXL', 'quantity': '0'},
   {'size': 'XL', 'quantity': '0'}],
  },
 **{'job_id': 'b1b4354e-7869-442a-8763-dafbd9f33a5a',
  'stock': '0',
  'mrp': 2799.0,
  'discount': 52.0,
  'margin': 'Low',
  }]**
```

Here the third element in the list doesn't have the inventory data key value pair. I would want to insert null value here in case of this information missing in the list

Thanks in advance for any leads here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method get from dict to set a default value.

If the key not exist the methos return NULL.

```
d = {"key":"value"}

d.get("key") 
# "value"

d.get("aloha") 
# None
```

You can pass a default value if the key doesn't exist too:

```
d.get("not exist","default")
# "default"
```

Reference [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html#c.PyDict_GetItem)